# Lunar Linux - small moonbase?

Tags: package-management, repository

I have successfully installed Lunar Linux. According to the manual, the command to install software is `lin [module name]`. This method worked for `gvim` and `sudo`, but the problem is that it appears that there is almost no software such as `xorg`, `neofetch`, `bspwm`, etc. in the moonbase.

What am I doing wrong or how can I expand the moonbase?

Comment: Compile them yourself if these are not part of you distribution.

Comment: Read your [distribution's wiki](http://wiki.lunar-linux.org/Lunar_Linux).  There's a section on the Moonbase, and one on how to install XOrg